# Integrability of $f+ g$

Tags: integration

I was reading a proof by Spivak on the integrability of $f+g$. Towards the end, he states

> Since $U(f,P) - L(f,P)$ and $U(g,P) - L(g,P)$ can be made as small as desired

And then he goes back to referring to the inequality (or rather the quantity)

$$U(f,P) + U(g,P) - [L(f,P) + L(g,P)] < \epsilon$$

can also be made as small as possible.

Now my question is, why is this explanation necessary? Because he originally got the inequality 
$$U(f,P) + U(g,P) - [L(f,P) + L(g,P)] < \epsilon$$

from the integrability of $f$ and $g$, thus $\epsilon$ can be made as small as desired. What's the point of saying it here again? Or is he really saying something else I didn't catch?

Also how does the quantities  $U(f,P) - L(f,P)$ and $U(g,P) - L(g,P)$ fit with the inequalities he had above? The inequalties involves  $U(f,P) + U(g,P)$ and  $L(g,P) + L(f,P)$

Finally does anyone know how to contact him or have his 4ed book? Because there is a minor typo that I found that has gone unnoticed for both his 2ed and 3ed of the book. It's not a "big" typo, but he forgot to capitalize "p" in $L(g,p)$.

Thanks a bunch

Comment: You can probably send him an email through the Publish or Perish website. But thst did get corrected in the 4e. It took me 5 minutes to find what you were talking about.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are two separate arguments. He has shown $f+g$ is integrable by getting upper and lower sum to differ by $<\varepsilon$ for a suitable partition. The subsequent argument is (by a squeeze argument) to establish that the integral is, in fact, the sum of the integrals of $f$ and $g$. This two-pronged argument is important to understand.

To be more specific, once you have established that $f+g$ is integrable, then we consider $\int_a^b (f+g)$. We see from Eq (1) that $\int_a^b (f+g)$ is between $L(f,P)+L(g,P)$ and $U(f,P)+U(g,P)$ for all partitions $P$. Likewise, by Eq (2), $\int_a^b f + \int_a^b g$ is between those same two numbers for all partitions $P$. Since those two numbers can be made arbitrarily close, there is a *unique* number between them. Therefore, $\int_a^b(f+g)$ and $\int_a^b f + \int_a^b g$ must be equal.

Comment: Yes but I still do not see what they have to do with the previous inequalities. $\int f + \int g$ are bounded by different quantities.

Comment: See the edit. I hope that helps.

Comment: No I am asking what does  $U(f,P) - L(f,P)$ and $U(g,P) - L(g,P)$ have to do with those bounds. They are different.

Comment: You need to phrase much more specific questions. You have a partition $P$ for which both of those are less than $\varepsilon/2$, for example. They can both be made arbitrarily small, so their sum, which is $\big(U(f,P)+U(g,P)\big)-\big(L(f,P)+L(g,P)\big)$, can be made arbitrarily small.